# AngularJS. Считывание данных из файла .txt и запись в переменную

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подскажите как получить данные из .txt файла и сравнить с тем что ввел пользователь.
str - то что ввел пользователь

```
$scope.praviloThree = function (str) {
        var count= 0;
        ///считать файл

        var text = ""
        for(var i =0; i<text.length; i++)
        {
            if(str == text)count++;
        }
        return count;
```

мне надо будет сравнить  123456 с str, и так со всем файлом

[image: так выглядят данные в файле]

Answer (score 0):

Получить данный файла можно только загрузив его через форму, ну а дальше разбить по строкам, в данном случае.

```
$('#file_button').on('change', function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function (e) {
           var rows = e.target.result.split(/\r\n/);
           for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // умная логика сравнения
           }
      };
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
});
```